# Increase number by 1 in loop when naming new sheet with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a loop that will take contents from 3 worksheets in a folder, and paste them onto a different workbook. I'd like to name them all a number. 1, 2, and 3 in the new workbook for use later while manipulating data.

I've tried naming a variable but I can't figure out how to have it increase by 1 each time.

```
Sub find()


Dim iIndex As Integer
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wb      As Workbook
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

strPath = "P:\SD\SUPPORT\File Load\"
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")

Do While strFile <> ""
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile)

 For iIndex = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(iIndex)

'Copy each worksheet into dual sub workbook
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Workbooks("Dual Sub.xlsm").Sheets(4)
ActiveSheet.Name = i + 1

Next iIndex

strFile = Dir 'This moves the value of strFile to the next file.
Loop


End Sub
```

With this code it just names the first sheet '2', and gives an error that it cannot name multiple sheets the same thing. I'd like for each sheet to be named as 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: You are trying to copy all the worksheets from the `wb` but you are referencing always the `ActiveSheet` when you should call it `wb.Sheets(i).Copy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your logic, this should do the trick:

```
Option Explicit
Sub find()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Masterwb As Workbook
    Set Masterwb = Workbooks("Dual Sub.xlsm")

    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    strPath = "P:\SD\SUPPORT\File Load\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")

    Dim i As Long
    i = i + 1
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile)
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets 'better to loop like this (you loop trhough every item in the workbooks.worksheets collection)
            ws.Copy After:=Masterwb.Sheets(Masterwb.Sheets.Count) 'copy the worksheet on the new workbook to the last index on the master workbook
            Masterwb.Sheets(Masterwb.Sheets.Count).Name = i 'name the last sheet on the master workbook the value of i starting from 1
            i = i + 1
        Next ws
        strFile = Dir 'This moves the value of strFile to the next file.
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: brilliant, Thank you!